# How is better to create frames in css than html?

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and want to know how is it better to create frames in css than html frames? For learning I want to create a screen with 2 equal sized frames, with the first frame divided into 2 columns. Can someone please guide me how do I start with it?

Comment: create the css inside your frame

Comment: frames are by definition a bad choice because they destroy the visitor's inherent understanding of the flow of the web -> the back button doesn't always go back to the previous view. Use a layout with `div`s and css' `position` or `flow`

Comment: Why don't you Google `css frames` before asking this?

Comment: What are css frames?
What did you try? Code would be helpful to elaborate what you're trying to do and say.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate frames by using `div` tags and the `overflow` CSS attribute.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/wPywB/

HTML...

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="col1">testing col1</div>
    <div class="col2">testing col2</div>
</div>
<div id="b">
    Test test test.
</div>
```

CSS...

```
#a, #b {
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#a .col1, #a .col2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;  
}
```

Optionally you can using some jQuery to dynamically set the height of the frame-like columns...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#a, #b').height( $(window).height() );
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#a, #b').height( $(window).height() );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got an example done for you. Just add the 'frame' class to a `div` and it will look like a frame. Works fine in IE5.5+ and Safari 5 (browsers that I tested).

Also added a 'border' class to simulate a frame 'drag' bar. But you probably want something more stylish. :P

[Click here for an example.](http://jsbin.com/orupe6)

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
html, body {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
body {
    background:lightgrey
}
.frame {
    float:left;
    width:49.5%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto
}
.frame .frame {
    background:cyan
}
.frame.border {
    border-right:3px ridge buttonface
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="frame border">
        <p>Left column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="frame">
        <p>Right column</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <p>Right frame</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this example does not work, the left and right columns are stacked.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks Guys!!! This is how I did:

CSS

```
    body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%; 
    }
#framecontent{
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 320px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    }

    #maincontent{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 130px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background: #fff;
    }

    .innermargin{
    margin: 15px;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="framecontent">
    <div class="innermargin">

    <h4>Search Result</h4>

    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="maincontent">
    <div class="innermargin">
    <h4>Search Criteria</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you got your answer from another answer, please do not post an answer yourself but accept the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use the Javascript frame library.
>
> don't forget to declare charset as Utf-8 in your head section:

`<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">`

```html
<div id="thewin"></div>
<script src="http://pastebin.com/raw/kR6B0XCY"></script>
<script>
   //you can create multiple frames to.
  createnewwindow("my frame","thewin","windowid","<h5>my contents</h5><button onClick=\"wht()\">change to white</button>");
  function wht(){
  setdefcol("white");  //optional semi transparent gray is default
  hidefrm("windowid")
  showfr("windowid");
  }
  </script>
```

Simple and easy solution.